# XPath to CSS Selector?

Tags: c#, xpath, css-selectors, html-agility-pack

How would you transform an xpath selector of the form:

```
/html[1]/body[1]/table[1]/tr[3]/td[1]/table[1]/tr[1]/td[2]/table[1]/tr[1]/td[2]
```

To it's css selector equivalent?

Alternatively I'd need to generate a CSS selector for an `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode`

Comment: You don't want a selector that long. There is no sensible reason you would want to do this. Please tell us why you think you need this....

Comment: (you could replace the `/` with a space and the `[\d]` with a nth-child(\d) I guess)

Comment: @sg3s: You'd need to replace `(?<!^)/` with `>` and not a space. If you wanted to replace with a space, you'd need to replace double slashes `//`.

Comment: @BoltClock I was oversimplifying it, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you absolutely **need** a CSS selector (most if not all HTML parsers and test suites support both CSS selectors *and* XPath), but what the heck:

```
html > body > table:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(1) > table:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2)
```

I'm only not including pseudo-classes for `html` and `body` because they're implied.

Comment: how do I use a CSS selector with HtmlAgilityPack?

Comment: @Nico: Oh, I was mistaken - HtmlAgilityPack doesn't support CSS selectors. Why would you need one, though?

Answer (score 0):

Are there no attributes (id or class) in any of these divs and tables? If there are this makes the htmlagilitypack's job much easier.